# How to change the install location of a package

Tags: arch-linux

I am running arch on a Chromebook, so I am lacking on storage. I got a external drive, formatted it and now I'm stuck not knowing how to install programs to the drive. How do I change the install location?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed arch with LVM support you can create a LVM and extend the volume:
Creating

To create a PV on /dev/sda1, run:

```
 pvcreate /dev/sda1
```

You can check the PV is created using the following command:

```
pvs
```

Growing

After extending or prior to reducing the size of a device that has a physical volume on it, you need to grow or shrink the PV using pvresize.

To expand the PV on /dev/sda1 after enlarging the partition, run:

```
 pvresize /dev/sda1
```

It has some caveats and pitfalls I suggest you to backup your data and read:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM

Comment: Your answer does not address the OP's question!

Comment: I can create and LVM and extend the partition to the SSD how does it not solve the problem?